# OrientDB unique index on properties of two connected vertices

Tags: orientdb

I have two vertex classes V1 and V2, both have the property 'id'.
I have one edge class, E.

V1's id property is a unique index, so all V1 have unique ids.
Now I want that all V2 instances connected to a certain V1 instance have unique ids.
So:

OK (and needed to work)

```
V1(id:"A") ---- E ----> V2(id:"a")
V1(id:"A") ---- E ----> V2(id:"b")
V1(id:"B") ---- E ----> V2(id:"a")
V1(id:"B") ---- E ----> V2(id:"b")
```

Not OK

```
V1(id:"A") ---- E ----> V2(id:"a")
V1(id:"A") ---- E ----> V2(id:"a")
```

Preferably, as an addition, it should also be possible for V2 instances to exist without edges and they should then be unique in the global scope. If this last part is not possible, the first part is helpful anyways.

Is this possible by database configuration / indexing (on edge or vertices) or do I have to enforce it in the application?

**UPDATE**

What I mean with by configuration / indexing is that it would be prevented (exception) if you were trying to add the edge (just like when using a unique index to enforce that only one edge exists between two vertices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only 2 ways to do this:

1. Put the V2 `id` attribute in the edge and call it `v2id`, so you can create an unique index against `out` + `v2id`
2. Create a hook (trigger) on `onBeforeCreate()` of class E and do your checks

Comment: The first option is only possible if the edge is mandatory since the id property applies to the entity described by the vertex. The handling will also be a bit messy since the id has different purposes. So I guess it is either option 2 or to handle it in the application / query. (See answer by @AlessandroRota below for a query example). I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
update e set out=(select from v1 where id="a"), in=(select from v2 where id="a") upsert where out=(select from v1 where id="a") and in=(select from v2 where id="a")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That might be useful, thanks. However I was wondering if there is some way of enforcing it on a deeper level (preventing them to ever be created). My guess is that it isn't possible? I managed to create unique edges by making an index on the edge for in and out, but this case is a bit more complex since it depends on properties of the in and out vertices of the edge (not only which vertex it is).

Comment: @dargolith I don't think it is possible